# WSS4JOutInterceptor Timestamp: How to change expiration duration?

Tags: cxf, ws-security

How do I change the duration of the timestamp? I seem to get five minutes as the default; I needed to change the duration to ten minutes.

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-36971e11-a696-4c24-a89a-45d6a562c594">
    <wsu:Created>2016-01-21T17:59:33.442Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2016-01-21T18:04:33.442Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

I needed to change the expiration time to ten minutes after the 'Created' time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found out: 
Set the `timeToLive` property to the number of seconds to expiration (default: 300)

```
wss4jOutProps.put("timeToLive", 600);
```